How to only print odd characters of a string in terminal?
Let's say I have a file with content "hheelllloo" and I want to clean it up and get "hello", how do I do this in bash?
echo "hheelllloo" | <?>


Are newline characters also duplicated?

Are there multibyte characters in the input? If so, is the duplication at byte level of character level. For example, would you get Ssttéépphhaannee (with each é being the two bytes 0xc3 0xa9) or SStt followed by 0xc3 0xc3 0xa9 0xa9 (not forming valid character) followed by pphhaannee?

Delete "odd" characters, or delete the second character of a pair of identical characters? What should the return be for the following? echo "1hheelllloo"

Are the characters always doubled or could you have input like hhellllo and, if so, what should the output be given that input?

One quick way is to take pairs of characters and keep only the first:
echo "hheelllloo" | sed -E 's/(.)./\1/g'
hello

It would be way more complicated to perform this within bash itself. You would have to iterate across the string picking out every alternate character. By the time you've done that you might as well have just called sed.
Note that per the question there is no attempt to ensure the characters are the same before the second of each pair is discarded. POSIX-compliant versions of sed allow back-references in the pattern match for BREs (but not EREs), so you can insist that it changes only pairs of matching characters:
echo "hrheelllloo" | sed 's/\(.\)\1/\1/g'
hrhello


strictly speaking, backreferences are part of POSIX basic regexes, but not part of ERE (surprisingly enough). So, echo "hrheelllloo" | sed 's/\(.\)\1/\1/g' should be ok, but the ERE variant might not work (and doesn't e.g. with the macOS sed).

in Bash only, you could do echo "hheelllloo" | while read -n2 tmp; do printf "%s" "${tmp:0:1}"; done; echo, to read two chars at a time and print the first of each pair. I don't suggest anyone to actually use that, but it's not that complicated.

@ilkkachu re backrefs and POSIX - that's very strange indeed. I'd say it was an oversight except that POSIX explicitly states they're valid only for BREs. Still feels wrong though

yep, it does feel odd. It's also rather explicitly mentioned in the FreeBSD re_format(7) man page, the final paragraph says "Obsolete ("basic") regular expressions differ in several respects. [...] Finally,  there is one new type of atom, a back reference: '' followed by a non-zero decimal digit d [...]".

It might be related to backreferences not being compatible with some algorithms for implementing the regex match, see Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast: "[...] The power that backreferences add comes at great cost: in the worst case, the best known implementations require exponential search algorithms, like the one Perl uses. Perl could not now remove backreference support, of course, but they could employ much faster algorithms when presented with regular expressions that don't have backreferences, [...]"

I suspect it's because POSIX is descriptive (describes how tools already behave) rather than subscriptive (define how a tool must behave) and while tools like awk exist that use EREs but do not treat \N as a backreference, POSIX can't describe \N in an ERE as meaning a backreference.

It's also important to note that there's a difference between allowing a backreference in a regexp vs allowing a backreference in a substitution string after a regexp has been matched. The POSIX regexp spec is defining what \N means in a BRE regexp as used in s/(.)\1/ in the 2nd script in the above answer, it's not defining what \N means in s/(.)./\1/ in the replacement string in the first script - THAT is defined in the POSIX sed spec

As for why awk (and apparently tcl and I suspect some other tools) don't allow backreferences in EREs - see the article that @ilkkachu provided for how much slower the type of regexp matching algorithm required to support backreferences can be than the type of regexp matching algorithm that doesn't support backreferences. The chart in that article of regexp/text size vs time at https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/grep1p.png comparing the 2 approaches (supports backrefs in red, does not support them in blue) demonstrates it nicely IMO.

As for why GNU sed (and I suspect some other tools) can choose to have \N (where N is a digit) mean a backreference in an ERE - that's because a digit is an "ordinary character", i.e. has no special meaning in a regexp, and POSIX says "The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped  ( \ ) is undefined" so that any tool can choose to implement \N as meaning whatever they want it to mean and still be POSIX compliant since \N is undefined behavior per POSIX.

@EdMorton, busybox awk does support back references with $0 ~ "(.)\\1" syntax  for instance. It also supports gawk's gensub() so you can do busybox awk '{print gensub("(.)\\1", "\\1", "g")}' here.

@StéphaneChazelas good to know, thanks. I assume you can use literal regexp delimiters /(.)\1/ and don't need to use dynamic regexp delimiters,"(.)\\1", and so avoid double-escaping the \. I've never actually had access to any system with busybox awk, it just always seems to come up as an exception to what almost every other awk does!

@EdMorton, well no /(.)\1/ matches any character followed by ^A as POSIX requires and as $0 ~ "(.)\1" does. For $1 ~ "(.)\\1" that should IMO be unspecified behaviour (and in practice the behaviour varies between implementations, not just busybox'), but if I remember the discussions around https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1105, POSIX ended up deciding otherwise.

@StéphaneChazelas After another look at the POSIX ERE spec, best I can tell \1 is undefined by POSIX since 1 is an ordinary character and "The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped  ( '' ) is undefined" so then what /(.)\1/ matches would be undefined and then that'd be why busybox can use $0 ~ "(.)\\1" (dynamic regexp notation) or $0 ~ /(.)\1/ (literal regexp notation) to match any character followed by itself.

To print every other character whatever they are, including newline which the other answers don't cover so far, you can do:
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/ = \2} $_ = substr $_, 0, 1'

That's assuming one byte character. If the input has UTF-8 encoded multibyte characters, add the -C option:
$ printf '¡¡HHoollaa\n\nMMuunnddoo!!\n\n' |
   perl -C -pe 'BEGIN{$/=\2} $_ = substr $_, 0, 1'
¡Hola
Mundo!

$/=\2 sets the record separator to a reference to the 2 number. In perl, that's how you request fixed length records.
So here, we're reading the input (with -p for the sed mode) 2 characters at a time and taking the first character our of each record with substr.
With GNU awk:
$ printf '¡¡HHoollaa\n\nMMuunnddoo!!\n\n' |
    gawk -v RS='(.)' 'NR%2{printf "%s", RT}'
¡Hola
Mundo!

With RS=(.) (a regexp that matches any character; . would not work as 1-character RS values are not treated as regexps), records are delimited by any character, so we get one empty record delimited by every character.
While $0 is empty, gawk makes what RS matched available in the RT special variable, and here we print it for every other record.

Here's a Rube Goldberg approach, for fun:
$ echo $(echo "hheelllloo" | fold -w1 | awk 'NR%2==1' | tr -d '\n')
hello

Here, fold -w 1 will break the input to one column, so one character per line (note that this expects plain ASCII and won't play well with Unicode), then awk NR%2==1 will print lines whose line number modulo 2 equals one, in other words, all the odd lines. Next, tr -d '\n' removes all newline characters to make it one line again and finally we echo the entire thing to add a final newline to the string.
Or, if you're into cryptic Perl code:
$ echo "hheelllloo" | perl -F"" -lane 'print grep {$i++ % 2} @F'
hello

This is adapted from here. The -a option makes perl operate like awk and split each input line into the array @F on the character given by -F. Since -F gives an empty string here, @F will have each character in a separate element of the array. Next, we look for cases where the value of incrementing the variable $i by 1 modulo 2 is not 0, which gives us the odd indices of the array.
I can't imagine any situation where either of these would be better than the simple sed approach the other answer gives though, so here's the same approach in perl, just because:
$ echo "hheelllloo" | perl -pe 's/(.)./$1/g'
hello


Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)

To delete "odd" characters in a string (i.e. every other character):
~$ echo "hheelllloo" | raku -pe 's:g/ (.) . /$0/;'
hello
~$ echo "1hheelllloo" | raku -pe 's:g/ (.) . /$0/;'
1hello
~$ echo "xyhheelllloo" | raku -pe 's:g/ (.) . /$0/;'
xhello
~$ echo "SSttéépphhaannee" | raku -pe 's:g/ (.) . /$0/;'
Stéphane
~$ echo "SSttéépphhaanneeXY" | raku -pe 's:g/ (.) . /$0/;'
StéphaneX


To delete the second character of a pair of identical characters:
~$ echo "hheelllloo" | raku -pe 's:g/ (. <same>) . /$0/;'
hello
~$ echo "1hheelllloo" | raku -pe 's:g/ (. <same>) . /$0/;'
1hello
~$ echo "xyhheelllloo" | raku -pe 's:g/ (. <same>) . /$0/;'
xyhello
~$ echo "SSttéépphhaannee" | raku -pe 's:g/ (. <same>) . /$0/;'
Stéphane
~$ echo "SSttéépphhaanneeXY" | raku -pe 's:g/ (. <same>) . /$0/;'
StéphaneXY


Above answers are coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages that provides high-level support for Unicode. Thanks to @terdon for Perl code, and to @StéphaneChazelas for raising the issue of multi-byte characters.
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org

Here is what I do for situations like yours. Break down the string to a list of one character per line (with grep -o .), use sed to print the odd lines (or even lines if you wish) and reconstruct the a new string by paste command.
Here is the command:
#for odd characters:
$ echo "hheelllloo" | grep -o . | sed -n '1~2 p' | paste -sd ''
hello

#for even characters:
$ echo "hheelllloo" | grep -o . | sed -n '2~2 p' | paste -sd ''
hello


That would produce output that's no longer a valid POSIX text line (or file) since it wouldn't have a terminating newline. Try piping that to wc -l or trying to read it to see a couple of examples of the kind of failure that causes. Any time you see tr -d '\n' in a script treat that script with a large grain of salt as it's probably producing output that relies on undefined behavior at best from subsequent text processing tools.

If you want to do that and produce valid POSIX text output then it'd need to be echo "hheelllloo" | { grep -o . | sed -n '1~2 p' | tr -d '\n'; echo ""; } or similar.

I am sure OP knows that he can simply put the whole command inside parenthesis as in newstring=$().

It's not obvious that the OP wants to do this in a subshell (as putting it inside $(...) would enforce) nor that they want to populate a variable from the output rather than just print it to stdout or pipe it to some other tool.
